# Tor Remote Desktop Client Tool

Tags: configuration, torsocks

I was curious if anyone knows if Tor (maybe Firefox more specific) supports any client tool (even betas) which would allow RDP port 3389 connections from the browser while on the Tor network?

The goal I'd like to accomplish would be to use RDP anonymously but I figured since Tor is good at doing tjis then maybe there is something already available.

It seems as if Tor is for web browsing anonymously only but I wasn't sure if you could use to the Tor network for other traffic as well other than just http or https so RDP for one example is my main question I suppose but if there's something related way more broader than that, I will consider anything.

I read about Torifying any application and I'm able to use Tails so any RDP client like Redimma, etc. which I can Torify will be fine. I also read that you have to use socat so I'm looking for pointers such as: use this and this as it works exactly like you are requesting.

Instructions for setup or where to find Tor IP or other settings would be nice but if that's too much here for all of this, I can put that in another question.

Comment: Tor can transport arbitrary TCP streams, so if it can use TCP it will work over Tor. If it will be anonymous is another question entirely.

Answer (score 1):

for socat:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:31337,reuseaddr,fork,bind=127.0.0.1 SOCKS4A:127.0.0.1:myserver.foo:3389,socksport=9050,socksuser=rdp
```

This will listen on TCP port 31337 at address 127.0.0.1 and for each incoming connection, connect through a SOCKS4A proxy to 127.0.0.1 on port 9050 (Tor) to myserver.foo on port 3389.

This won't work on Tails, due to it's strict packetfilter ("firewall").

Now connect your RDP client to 127.0.0.1:31337 and it will really be communicating with myserver.foo:3389 over Tor.

I cannot speak to (or even speculate) the anonymity of the RDP protocol, it is proprietary and the [legal status of FLOSS implementations is unknown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#Patents) (however I think people doing Microsoft's work for them will likely not get shut down or sued until Microsoft is ready to release a competing product for Linux), and their code likely unreviewed from an anonymity or privacy perspective.

RDP, as a protocol, has functionality for sharing local devices (microphone, webcam, disk drives), resources (clipboard) and network resources (network mounted shared). If it's possible that the remote server may be malicious or could be made malicious (e.g. it's not hardware that you physically own), you should use it with caution.

Beware also of the possibility of a man-in-the-middle trying to strip or subvert any cryptographic exchanges, **consider using an onion service**, this would both allow it to work within Tails packetfilter (onion services are automatically torified) and provide a known-good protection against possible man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any TCP-based service. Try to use VNC+[noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) or X11 + [js/html5 X server](https://github.com/GothAck/javascript-x-server). It will be 100% in-Tor/in-browser solution for easy connections. If you're serious about using it extensively - X11+ssh is your very best friend